# Save info from Contact Form 7 to textarea field ACF

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, contact-form-7, acfpro

i have a simple form CF7 with 3 strings in every post of my site.

How i can save information from every sended form to my textarea filed (ACF) by row, look like:

**textarea field:**
name1 surname1 phone1
name2 surname2 phone2
name2 surname2 phone2
name2 surname2 phone2

Comment: you should use some hooks provided by CF7. But is not clear on which action you 
want to update your ACF fields. You could use for example `wpcf7_mail_sent` (this would be initiated after the mail is sent) hook and update your fields as required

Comment: @fefe With CF7 everything clear. But not with ACF. I know hook update_field(), but it's not quite what i need (i think)

Comment: can you provide some snippet what have you been trying?

Comment: @fefeI decided to first ask for some tips here, because I didn’t figure out how to write it right

Answer (score 0):

@fefe but i have my old code to another site to update sub filed

```
add_action('wp_ajax_block', 'send_report_callback');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_block', 'send_report_callback' );
function send_report_callback() {
$vars = explode('_', $_POST['block']);
$save = update_sub_field( array('days', $vars[0], 'times', $vars[1], 'block'), 1, 
$_POST['id']);
$save = update_sub_field( array('days', $vars[0], 'times', $vars[1], 'info'), 
$_POST['info'], $_POST['id']);
echo $save;
die();
}
```